# Skip SAS job when Source data doesn't exist?

Tags: unix, sas, autosys

In our project, we use autosys tool for SAS jobs scheduling and command in thel Autosys command is like:
sas autoexec.sas

Existing process is, we have source data check job and it loops for 12 times each loop waits for 30mins. If we don't get data in 12 loops datacheck job got failed and main sas jib won't run because of dependency.

We got a scenario like even though source data not available, datacheck job should be successful only and next sas main job should be success with out run the code. So that next autosys job will run.

Please suggest how can we achieve this ine easy way.

Comment: Please be more specific on the data: is it SAS datasets (with fixed or variable name), lines in anexisting SAS dataset, spreadsheets what? Does `x 'pwd';` work in your installation? _We also expect you to share the code you are currently using (replacing company specifics with dummies like /my/folder/myFile.xyz)._

Comment: Show your code.  Are you trying to say that the next SAS job should run after waiting 6 hours (12 waits @ 30 minutes each), or do you want all your SAS jobs to run concurrently (in parallel)?  Parallel will be easy if no job#(x+k) is dependent on job#(x), although you might run low on resources.